# How to find which queries are being run at a particular time

Tags: performance, sql-server-2016, monitoring

I have successfully implemented the tip [described here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3193/automated-collection-of-sql-server-database-connections-for-monitoring/) to automate the collection of SQL Server database connections. I am getting the messages when this occurs and I have narrowed down the issues to a couple of databases.
I would like to have some more details on which resources are accessed and what are the queries being run when this occurs.

Any clue on how I could hook up a process to gather that information?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with an extended event to retrieve the queries you need to find.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

[image]

Depending on what you need to find you can use one of the many Events. Few which I think you might need are:

- rpc_completed
- sql_batch_completed

And if you need the statements in it:

- sp_statement_completed
- sql_statement_completed

ps. Don't forget to add one or more filter predicates to prevent overhead.

Comment: It appears to go beyond my knowledge. Does anything a touch easier?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on the link?

Comment: At first I got scared but reading the tutorial ! But eventually I have implemented what is shown in it, and it worked. But from then I tried to find my way thru the multiple options available in the events filtering with "connections" or "login" but couldn't find one fitting what I need to know which is the list of resources (active queries or views) when the number of connections exceeds 20.

Comment: ChatGPT suggested the query shown below but it is coming up with a syntax error on the 1st  DB_ID('YourDatabaseName') 

ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.database_name, sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.session_id, sqlserver.username)
    WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID('YourDatabaseName') AND 
        sqlserver.session_id IN (
            SELECT session_id
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
            WHERE database_id = DB_ID('YourDatabaseName') AND is_user_process = 1
            GROUP BY session_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
        )
)

Comment: It seems that the query suggested by ChatGPT forgot to consider that the WHERE predicate for extended events does not support IN or subqueries

Comment: Thats quite an addition to the first question, I think it may be done with just querieing the extended event file.